# page not found after restoring from the backup except home page (Tried all solutions, which I got through googling)?

Tags: migrations, backups

I restored my site from the backup taken from another computer. Another drupal site is working fine in my machine, but this site which I restored from a backup is not working fine.

I am able to see the home page, front page but not any other pages of this restored site. when I click on links displaying 404 error (page not found).

When it is working for some other site, it has to work for other also. But I am missing some site specific configurations.

could any body please help me in this regard

Comment: clear your cache and check if it works.

Comment: unable to get to that configuration page also ...

Comment: And if you will use http://example.com/index.php?q=node/1 or http://example.com/index.php?q=admin what can you see?

Comment: example.com/index.php?q=admin is working, but not index.php?q=node/1

Comment: @Chella please answer @ (at) me next time. Maybe you don't have node 1 ;) It looks like your htaccess was not in backup, or if it was in backup, it wasn't restored. If it is there, `diff` it with Drupal's core htaccess from fresh download from drupal.org

Comment: is .htaccess exist in root folder?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have lost your .htaccess in the process. Download [newest Drupal core from Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/project/drupal), extract it and put .htaccess in the root directoy of your Drupal. If this still does not work, and your .htaccess is ignored, go to [official Clean URLs documentation](https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls), and find a section **Server configuration for Clean URLs on a dedicated server, with httpd.conf** - this should show you how to configure it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in this way,
I gone to  mysite.com/index.php?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls

I turned off clean urls.. My site working now...!

Comment: Pretty OK workaround, but not a fix for long run.

Comment: why is it not a fix for long run??

Comment: Because not having clean URLs is bad for business, it makes your site use `?q=` in all addresses, and most people would mistype that, so you can't really put it on posters, flyers or product boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Hello its all about Clean URL enable to your site, so just got to

**?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls**

and turned off clean url

your issue will be sort out

Answer (score 0):

Check Apache config.
Maybe this config is missing

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted